# How to insert "The last time" into a simple question?

Tags: phrase-usage, expressions

I would like to ask someone about his last payment using the expression "The last time". I know that I can say ; " When was your last or latest payment? " but I'd like to learn how to use the expression "The last time".

So how can I mix (When did you pay?) and (The last time)?

I thought of a few options but I don't know which is correct and sounds more colloquial (native).

1. When was the last time you paid?
2. When was the last time that you paid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought of a few options but I don't know which is correct and
>   sounds more colloquial (native).
>
> 1. When was the last time you paid?
> 2. When was the last time that you paid?

I would say number 1 because:
1. It is less words and still makes sense
2. When I say this out loud I trip over the **that** it feels in the way, that may just be habit.

Answer (score 1):

Both work, but out of habit I'd be much more likely to say the first sentence. The 2nd one sounds a bit more formal, but you can omit the word *that* and no one would think much of it.